# Count triplets - First Approch

Tags: java, math

I'm doing this exercise on HackerRank:

> You are given an array and you need to find number of triplets of indices (i, j, k) such that the elements at those indices are in geometric progression for a given common ratio r and i < j < k.

Full exercise: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/count-triplets-1/problem
I have problems with compiler.
This is code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class Solution {

    // Complete the countTriplets function below.
    static long countTriplets(List<Long> arr, long r) {
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length() - 2; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length() - 1; j++) {
                if (arr[j] - arr[i] == r) {
                    for (int k = j + 1; k < arr.length(); k++) {
                        if (arr[k] - arr[j] == r) {
                            System.out.println("(" + arr[i] + "," + arr[j] + "," + arr[k] + ")");
                            counter++;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        ;
        return counter;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        String[] nr = bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" ");

        int n = Integer.parseInt(nr[0]);

        long r = Long.parseLong(nr[1]);

        List<Long> arr = Stream.of(bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" ")).map(Long::parseLong)
                .collect(toList());

        long ans = countTriplets(arr, r);

        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(ans));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

        bufferedReader.close();
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
}
```

I have this errors:

```
Solution.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length() -2; i++){
                       ^
  symbol:   method length()
  location: variable arr of type List<Long>
Solution.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    for(int j = i + 1; j < arr.length() -1; j++){
                              ^
  symbol:   method length()
  location: variable arr of type List<Long>
Solution.java:21: error: array required, but List<Long> found
          if(arr[j] - arr[i] == r){
                ^
Solution.java:21: error: array required, but List<Long> found
          if(arr[j] - arr[i] == r){
                         ^
Solution.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
            for(int k = j + 1; k < arr.length(); k++){
                                      ^
  symbol:   method length()
  location: variable arr of type List<Long>
Solution.java:23: error: array required, but List<Long> found
                if(arr[k] - arr[j] == r){
                      ^
Solution.java:23: error: array required, but List<Long> found
                if(arr[k] - arr[j] == r){
                               ^
Solution.java:24: error: array required, but List<Long> found
System.out.println("(" +arr[i] + "," +arr[j] + "," +arr[k] +")");
                           ^
Solution.java:24: error: array required, but List<Long> found
System.out.println("(" +arr[i] + "," +arr[j] + "," +arr[k] +")");
                                         ^
Solution.java:24: error: array required, but List<Long> found
System.out.println("(" +arr[i] + "," +arr[j] + "," +arr[k] +")");
                                                       ^
10 errors
```

(I'm starting out with programming, so I don't know if the code is correct)

=============================================================================

**UPDATE:** I don't have errors, but return 0 for each test cases.

```
public class Solution {

    // Complete the countTriplets function below.
    static long countTriplets(List<Long> arr, long r) {

        // Long[] a = arr.toArray();
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size() - 2; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.size() - 1; j++) {
                if (arr.get(j) - arr.get(i) == r) {
                    for (int k = j + 1; k < arr.size(); k++) {
                        if (arr.get(k) - arr.get(j) == r) {
                            System.out.println("(" + arr.get(i) + "," + arr.get(j) + "," + arr.get(k) + ")");
                            counter++;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: arr variable is a List instance, try using arr.size() instead of arr.lenght()

Comment: Why use size() instead of length()?

Comment: Because lenght() is a method of the type Array while your parameter is of type List. size() is the same as length just for List objects. The error comes from the fact that method lenght doesn't exist for object of type List. Try size() ;)

Comment: Also don't use arr[k] but use arr.get(k) for the same reason as above ;)

Comment: It works, but now give me 0 as result for each test cases

Comment: The way you are trying to solve the triple-count problem, I don't think you can pass all test cases, because the time complexity of your code is O(n^3). There are faster techniques available.

Comment: @CamiCode - If one of the answers resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking it as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Comment: No I couldn't solve it so I can't say it's completed or fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The input type for variable arr is a List and not an array of integers. List is an interface of Collection.

int[] arr = new int[]; // is the way to declare and array any element can be accessed by using arr[index]

A list can contain duplicates and elements are ordered. 
Example implementations are LinkedList (linked list based) and ArrayList (dynamic array based).

arr.size() is the function to get size of the collection. Also, in order to access any element in a list arr.get(index) function is used.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are mixing up two similar, but in the end: very different concepts.

```
static long countTriplets(List<Long> arr, long r) {
```

It seems you want to think of `arr` as of **array**. Because you later use the **array access** syntax `arr[someIndex]`.

But well, you didn't declare it as **array**. You have a **List** there.

Then you have to use things like:

```
someList.getSize()
```

to acquire the **length** of the list, or

```
someList.get(someIndex)
```

to acquire a specific element in that list.

But the real answer is: when you don't understand such fundamental basic stuff, then fetching some code from somewhere, to turn it to hackerrank isn't what you should be doing right now.

Meaning: in order to successfully write your own code, to solve such exercises, you need to understand "enough" of the language already.

Thus: step back, and get a good book about Java. And work through that book.

Comment: I did Java but I'm a bit rusty, but I agree with you on the last point. I would follow your advice but there are many "tips" on the net and I wouldn't know what to choose.

Comment: @CamiCode I see you upvoted some answers. Is there a specific reason why you didnt accept an answer? SOmething missing for you?

Comment: I didn't accept any answer because I don't know which one to choose. Also I still have the problem that my function returns to 0

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct the following couple of errors:

A. Use `arr.length` instead of `arr.length()`

B. Convert `arr` into an array before you use it in `for` loops. First, rename the `List<Long> arr` parameter in `countTriplets(List<Long> arr, long r)` e.g. as `List<Long> list` and then use the following code to convert it into a `Long` array:

```
Object []objectArray=list.toArray();
Long arr[] = Arrays.stream(objectArray).map(Object::toString)
                                       .map(Long::valueOf)
                                       .toArray(Long[]::new);
```

Comment: When going array, then you should go down the full nine yards ... and have an array of **l**ong in the end ;-)